How Ably works with Vercel?
I'm using Ably as provider for my Express application. Vercel itself suggests to use Ably, among others, to manage websockets.
The issue is that once my deployed application successfully connects to Ably, it can no longer publish or subscribe to channels. It appears that something is blocking the communication in any direction. Everything works perfectly on localhost, so I suspect the problem is related to Vercel's configuration.
Here the dependencies used in the project:
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.11.97",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.8",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "eslint": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-config-standard-with-typescript": "^43.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.2",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 ",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.0",
    "pre-commit": "^1.2.2",
    "prettier": "^3.2.5",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.4",
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "tsx": "^4.9.3",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5",
    "webpack": "^5.91.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.17",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/node": "^20.11.22",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.1.0",
    "ably": "^2.0.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "fp-ts": "^2.16.6",
    "io-ts": "^2.2.21",
    "mongodb": "^6.6.0",
    "mongoose": "^8.3.3",
    "random-words": "^2.0.1",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1"
  }

The vercel.json is:
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "dist/bundle.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node",
      "config": { "includeFiles": ["dist/**"] }
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "dist/bundle.js",
      "methods": ["GET", "POST", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],
      "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      }
    }
  ]
}


Any idea on what it could cause this?

Are you trying to use Ably subscription in your backend logic?

That's correct. I subscribe to a channel in order to get messages from the client. For some reason this wouldn't work in my backend logic

The issue is that Vercel has a default execution timeout for their backend functions (serverless functions). This means that within about 10 seconds, the Ably connection would time out. As a result, the backend subscriptions were not triggering. On the local machine there is no execution timeout, that's why it works fine.
Vercel's backend runs as a serverless function, designed to be stateless and short-lived. And Ably Realtime's connections are persistent and maintain state over time.
There are several options you can explore:

Use a regular Ably Rest client instance for publishing (Rest client doesn't have state and will work as expected in serverless environment). Subscribe on the client side via Ably Realtime and invoke the necessary backend logic from your frontend using a simple REST API.
Use Ably Webhooks if the first option is not suitable for you.

